# Ubuntu 11.10 in VirtualBox does not show anything on the desktop

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

[image]

The buttons that should be visible still function (as shown by the drop down menu I clicked). My host is Windows 7.

VirtualBox settings

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Are you talking about the thumbnail that is in the VirtualBox Manager? Or are you talking about the desktop of the actual virtual machine not showing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed something when installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

This should help you: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

[image]